# SQL to update linked server table with a where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to update a linked server table `jj_rec` based on two columns, how can i do that?

I am able to update with below SQL with just one column condition

```
UPDATE central.carstrain.informix.jj_rec SET
    LINE1 = 'Barcode' where id=340059
```

But it fails when I include an extra condition `aa='PERM'`. Any help is appreciated.

```
UPDATE central.carstrain.informix.jj_rec SET
    LINE1 = 'Barcode' where id=340059 and aa='PERM'
```

I am sure `jj_rec` table has the column '`aa`'. This happens to me always for other tables also when i have more than one condition in where clause.

Comment: What data type is "aa"? if varchar or nvarchar, what is its length?

Comment: aa  is of  char(4). Error is ...

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "central" returned message "
[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Error in row.".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "central" returned message "[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Unspecified System Error =  -21005.".
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "central".

Comment: did you try: `select * from central.carstrain.informix.jj_rec where id=340059` and `select * from central.carstrain.informix.jj_rec where id=340059 and aa='PERM'`

Comment: I wonder if enclosing each condition in brackets would help. Informix [doesn't seem to require that](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls680.htm "Using a Condition in the WHERE Clause (IBM Informix Guide to SQL: Syntax)") but maybe the ODBC driver does or there's some other reason for that when the linked server is an Informix server. Just a wild guess.

Comment: This works...!! select * from central.carstrain.informix.jj_rec where id=340059 and aa='PERM'

Comment: Enclosing in brackets also doesn't work...